# Pyomo dynamic optimisation ERROR: variable that is not attached to an active block on the submodel being written

Tags: optimization, dynamic, pyomo

I am trying to set up a model for a dynamic optimisation problem with pyomo.DAE.
I defined my state variable as well as it's corresponding Derivative (both indexed by m.Time). I then set up a simple constraint that expresses the relationship between state and derivative variable in the most simple terms. Solving the problem with a dummy objective (so just testing the constraint), I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Model contains an expression (calc_my_state[0]) 
that contains a variable (derivative_var[0]) that is not 
attached to an active block on the submodel being written
```

Here's an excerpt of what I wrote:

(.....)

```py
m.state_var = Var(m.Time, initialize=0)
m.derivative_var = DerivativeVar(m.state_var, wrt=m.Time)

def calc_my_state(m,i):
   return m.derivative_var[i] == m.state_var[i]*2
m.calc_my_state = Constraint(m.Time, rule=calc_my_state)

m.obj = Objective(expr=1)

opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
results = opt.solve(m)
```

I tried to reproduce the simple setup of an DAE in pyomo, more or less copied and pasted lines from the [pyomoDAE docu](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modeling_extensions/dae.html#modeling-components).
I printed derivative_var.get_state_var() and it gives me the right state variable without error.
I also tried solving simple DAE examples that I found on the internet and solving them with my solver settings worked fine as well.

What am I missing? I am grateful for any input!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the missing link: I did not specify the "Discretization Transformation". Once something like the following was added, the script ran without error!

```py
    discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
    discretizer.apply_to(m, wrt=m.Time)
```